# MATLAB: svds() is not converging

Tags: matlab, octave, svd

So using MATLAB's [svds()](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/svds.html) function on some input data as such:

```
[U, S, V, flag] = svds(data, nSVDs, 'L')
```

I noticed that from run to run with the same data, I'd get drastically different output SVD sizes from run to run. When I checked whether 'flag' was set, I found that it was, indicating that the SVDs had not converged. My normal system here would be that if it really needs to converge, I'd do something like this:

```
flag = 1
svdOpts = struct('tol', 1e-10, 'maxit', 600, 'disp', 0);
while flag:
    if svdOpts.maxit > 1e6
        error('There''s a real problem here.')
    end

    [U, S, V, flag] = svds(data, nSVDs, 'L', svdOpts)
    svdOpts.maxit = svdOpts.maxit*2
end
```

But from what I can tell, when you use 'L' as the third argument, the fourth argument is ignored, meaning I just have to deal with the fact that it's not converging? I'm not even really sure how to use the 'sigma' argument in place of the 'L' argument. I've also tried reducing the number of SVDs calculated to no avail. Any help on this matter would be much appreciated.

**EDIT**
While following up on the comments below, I found that the problem had to do with the way I was building my data matrices. Turned out I had accidentally inverted a matrix and had an input of size (4000x1) rather than (20x200), which was what was refusing to converge.  **This was not the problem**

**Second Edit**
If anyone is still following this, I was actually wrong, and my data had only converged because I scaled the inputs wrong. Here is a program to generate the data as I'm generating them:

```
%  Generate data for SVD failure to converge
% Kernel functions
data_fun1 = @(t, tau)(exp(-t*(1./tau)));
t = linspace(0, 10, 26)';
tau1 = logspace(-1, log10(5), 150); 
k1 = data_fun1(t, tau1);

gamma = 4257;
n = 6;
tau = 0.075;
A = -(2/3)*(2*pi*gamma)^2*n*tau.^3;

data_fun2 = @(V, t)exp(A*t*(V.^2));
V = linspace(0, 0.4, 29);
tau3 = logspace(-1, log10(5), 150)';
tau3 = tau3*1e-5;
k2 = data_fun2(V, tau3)';

svdOpts = struct('tol', 1e-10, 'maxit', 1e3, 'disp', 0);
svdOpts2 = svdOpts;
flag = 1;
while flag
    if svdOpts2.maxit > 1e8
        break
    end

    [U1, S1, V1, flag] = svds(k1, length(t), 'L', svdOpts);
    svdOpts2.maxit = svdOpts2.maxit * 2;
end
flag
% flag == 0
flag = 1;

while flag
    if svdOpts2.maxit > 1e8
        break
    end

    [U2, S2, V2, flag] = svds(k2, length(V), 'L', svdOpts);
    svdOpts2.maxit = svdOpts2.maxit * 2;
end
flag
% flag == 1
```

I've also tried letting it run out to svdOpts2.maxit > 1e9, but that ran all weekend and never got past 4.096e8. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: If it's not too big, can you post the `data` matrix? Or a plot of a few of its singular values on those occasions where `svds` converges? It would help us understand the kind of data you're dealing with.

Comment: `svds(data, nSVDs, 'L', svdOpts)` is OK: the third argument can be a real number or 'L'. In either case the fourth argument is read.

Comment: Please post also `nSVDS, size(data), nnz(data), is sparse(data)`

Answer (score 0):

The example you provide fails because you are trying to compute the full SVD decomposition by `svds(A,k)` which should be used only if `k < min(size(A))`. And I should add *much much* less.

For your example `svd()` should be used.

With `k2` computed by the code above

```
>> tic, [U2, S2, V2, flag] = svds(k2, length(V), 'L'); toc         
Elapsed time is 0.830326 seconds.
>> flag

flag =

     1

>> tic, [U2, S2, V2] = svd(k2); toc      
Elapsed time is 0.002851 seconds.
>> norm(U2*S2*V2'-k2)/norm(k2)

ans =

   8.4982e-16


>> max(max(abs(U2*S2*V2'./k2-1)))

ans =

   5.8111e-12
```

Please remember that a rectangular matrix `A` has only `min(size(A))` singular values, so indeed you are interested in computing *all* singular values. If you are interested in a *square* `S2` you should use `svd(k2, 'econ')`.